Why does backdrop-filter: blur break whenever unrelated elements are animated
I'm building a website, and use the backdrop-filter: blur(12px) CSS effect on my navbar. Whenever I created a CSS animation to animate the text on my page, the blur filter disappeared. This affected all the elements on my page.
Here is an example of the problem.


<head>
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: rgb(8, 8, 8);
      color: white;
    }
    
    .header {
      position: fixed;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
    }
    
    .navbar {
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: column;
      margin: auto;
      border-radius: 16px;
      width: 40%;
      padding: 1rem;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      min-height: 48;
      backdrop-filter: blur(12px);
      border: 1px solid hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.1);
    }
    
    .text {
      display: flex;
      margin: auto;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    .fadeIn span {
      opacity: 0;
      filter: blur(12px);
      transform: translateX(-20px) translateY(30px);
      animation: fadeIn 1s ease-out forwards;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .fadeIn span:nth-of-type(1) {
      animation-delay: 0.3s;
    }
    
    @keyframes fadeIn {
      to {
        filter: blur(0px);
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0) translateY(0);
      }
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="navbar">
        <a href="/">Home</a>
        <a href="/test">Test</a>
        <a href="/about">About</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="text fadeIn">
      <h1><span>Here is my content</span></h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>



If you remove the fadeIn class from the text, the issue goes away. I believe this has to do with the combination of filter and transform, but wanted to confirm my suspicions. I have done some research, and others have said that there is an issue in chrome that may cause this, but supposedly it's been patched.
Any solutions would be greatly appreciated!

Try adding z-index: 1 to .header.
.header {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  /* added */
  z-index: 1;
}

It seems when an animation applied to .fadeIn, it changes the stacking order. Thus you need to explicitly assign the stacking order of the element with backdrop-filter with a higher z-index. Otherwise it will not affect the elements on top of it.


<head>
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: rgb(8, 8, 8);
      color: white;
    }
    
    .header {
      position: fixed;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      /* added */
      z-index: 1;
    }
    
    .navbar {
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: column;
      margin: auto;
      border-radius: 16px;
      width: 40%;
      padding: 1rem;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      min-height: 48;
      backdrop-filter: blur(12px);
      border: 1px solid hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.1);
    }
    
    .text {
      display: flex;
      margin: auto;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    .fadeIn span {
      opacity: 0;
      filter: blur(12px);
      transform: translateX(-20px) translateY(30px);
      animation: fadeIn 1s ease-out forwards;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .fadeIn span:nth-of-type(1) {
      animation-delay: 0.3s;
    }
    
    @keyframes fadeIn {
      to {
        filter: blur(0px);
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0) translateY(0);
      }
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="navbar">
        <a href="/">Home</a>
        <a href="/test">Test</a>
        <a href="/about">About</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="text fadeIn">
      <h1><span>Here is my content</span></h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>




This was the issue. Thank you!
